# Sort with tinysort and data attribute

Tags: jquery, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to sort a list based on data attributes with **tinysort**.

First the list:

```
<ul id="late-services" class="list">
<li data-service-id="23" data-criticality="1000">
    <span>Service 23</span>
    <span class="list-collapse ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span>
    <span class="service-zone">Cannes</span>
    <div class="list-item-belly" style="display: none;">
        <div>Deadline dans 1 semaine.</div>
        <div>Le client n'a pas confirmé.</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li data-service-id="22" data-criticality="2000">
    <span>Service 22</span>
    <span class="list-collapse ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span>
    <span class="service-zone">Cannes</span>
    <div class="list-item-belly" style="display: none;">
        <div>Deadline dans 1 semaine.</div>
        <div>Le client n'a pas confirmé.</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li data-service-id="24" data-criticality="500">
    <span>Service 24</span>
    <span class="list-collapse ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span>
    <span class="service-zone">Cannes</span>
    <div class="list-item-belly" style="display: none;">
        <div>Deadline dans 1 semaine.</div>
        <div>Le client n'a pas confirmé.</div>
    </div>
</li>               
</ul>
```

And then the call to tinysort:

```
$('ul#late-services>li').tsort('li', {data:'serviceId'});
```

I must be doing something wrong but don't know what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya  **working demo** of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/15/

**Updated:** Implementation using `data: (option)` here: http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/49/
  & http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/52/  [code]$('ul#late-services>li').tsort('span',{data:'serviceid'});​

Helpful link: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

**issue was** 1) noticed wrong attr value inside **and 2)** inside tsort no li is required notice the difference here: `$('ul#late-services>li').**tsort({attr:'data-service-id'})**;​`

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/scripts/jquery.tinysort.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
<ul id="late-services" class="list">
<li data-service-id="23" data-criticality="1000">
    <span>Service 23</span>
    <span class="list-collapse ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span>
    <span class="service-zone">Cannes</span>
    <div class="list-item-belly" style="display: none;">
        <div>Deadline dans 1 semaine.</div>
        <div>Le client n'a pas confirmé.</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li data-service-id="22" data-criticality="2000">
    <span>Service 22</span>
    <span class="list-collapse ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span>
    <span class="service-zone">Cannes</span>
    <div class="list-item-belly" style="display: none;">
        <div>Deadline dans 1 semaine.</div>
        <div>Le client n'a pas confirmé.</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li data-service-id="24" data-criticality="500">
    <span>Service 24</span>
    <span class="list-collapse ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span>
    <span class="service-zone">Cannes</span>
    <div class="list-item-belly" style="display: none;">
        <div>Deadline dans 1 semaine.</div>
        <div>Le client n'a pas confirmé.</div>
    </div>
</li>               
</ul>


    </body>
</html>
​
```

**JqueryCode**

```
$('ul#late-services>li').tsort({attr:'data-service-id'});​
```

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Same comment here, what is wrong with the tinysort data setting ?

Comment: Ah, okies here is the explanation (i have not used this plugin much but heres what i found) : see the working data here: http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/44/ **And** another implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/49/ so the tiny sort uses the .data() query api to find your text but if you are not wrapping your serviceid,.. in "" (quotes) it doesn't find anything I will update my answer hope JSfiddle help you to understand better, cheers

Comment: mmh in your example if I replace $('ul#late-services>li').tsort('span',{data:'foo'});​ by $('ul#late-services>li').tsort({data:'serviceid'});​, it doesn't work better.

Comment: Cooleos, I had 2 samples for playing around try this http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/52/  , Please note with data: option somehow I need to mention the **span** where as with attr option I don't have a look here:http://jsfiddle.net/wJzNE/52/ ; **Srry** I lost my editing right son the comment above else I could removed some verbal mistakes in there :) Hope this helps, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In your case this one should work:
$('ul#late-services').tsort('li', {attr:'data-service-id'});

Comment: Am I misusing the tinysort 'data' setting ?